# Template for latex export in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode

I would like to create a template called "my-article", with specified packages and settings to be exported to latex from org-mode. How can I do this?

PS: the instructions for org-mode<8.0 does not work as in here http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-latex-export.html

Thanks

Comment: Are there any additional details you can provide as to why you believe the instructions do not work?  Does Emacs beep, or blink, or do the Hokey-Pokey?  Have you tried increasing the error message generating capabilities of Emacs by placing this in your `.emacs` file?:  `(setq debug-on-error t)`  Does it give an error message in the `*Messages*` buffer?  If so, please post your error messages in the question.  Does it freeze?  Does it generate some type of export output, but not what you expect? . . .

Comment: instead of `org-export-latex-classes` it's now `org-latex-classes`.

Comment: wvxvw, that is exactly it. May I ask you where you found that information? I couldn't find it anywhere. Also, where you get information when such instructions change from one version to another? Thanks

Comment: You can find it in the manual.  http://orgmode.org/org.html.  Developers update the manual when they make changes.  Not Worg.  In fact, there's a hint at the top of the page you link to: "*LaTeX Export for Org Mode **< 8.0***"